# Is There Any Way to Stop the Execution of Subsequent Event Listeners in Spring?

Tags: spring

I have a defined `ApplicationEvent` and a series of its listeners. The listeners are properly arranged with the `Ordered` interface.

Amidst the execution of my first listener, there are business-level checks that determines whether the rest of logic (from subsequent listeners) shall apply. If this check fails, all of the subsequent event listeners should not be executed.

The business-level context is not available to the event publisher hence I am not able to do checks before publishing the event.

Solutions I myself can think of:

1. Throwing an uncheck exception. This is what I am currently doing but does not look clean
2. Performing the check at the start of every subsequent listeners. This wastes a lot of resources doing repetitive checks and is error prone, since new listeners (without implementing the `Ordered` interface) may be added.
3. Making the first listener the only one that listens to this type of event, and after it processes it, publish the event wrapped in another type. This seem like the way to go however I just want to understand if there are better alternatives.

Thank you!